# помогите решить задачу JS

Tags: javascript, if, for, while

Нужно обновить функцию `canTheyBook` так, чтобы она принимала третий аргумент `babiesCount` и немного обновить требования:

- номер вмещает не более 8 человек, но 9-ым можно подселить младенца;
- должен быть как минимум один взрослый;
- на одного взрослого может быть не более 2-х детей и младенцев;
- младенцев можно разместить на кроватях для взрослых, поэтому в номере может быть больше чем один младенец (если выполняются другие условия).

```js
function canTheyBook(adultsCount = 0, childrenCount = 0, babiesCount = 0) {
    let sum = adultsCount + childrenCount <= 8 + babiesCount;
    let div = childrenCount  <= 2 * adultsCount;
    let hasAdults = adultsCount > 0;
    
    return sum && div && hasAdults
}
```

Comment: При чем здесь кровати? По условиям может быть 3 взрослых и 6 младенцев, например. Так?

Comment: canTheyBook(2, 3, 1) === true - Бронирование разрешено. ////
canTheyBook(8, 0, 1) === true - Бронирование разрешено. ////
canTheyBook(4, 2, 3) === true - Бронирование разрешено. ////
canTheyBook(0, 1, 1) === false - Нельзя бронировать без взрослых ////
canTheyBook(9) === false - Слишком много людей ////
canTheyBook(8, 1) === false - Ребёнок не может быть 9-ым ////
canTheyBook(2, 2, 3) === false - Недостаточно взрослых ////

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
function canTheyBook(adultsCount = 0, childrenCount = 0, babiesCount = 0) {
    let sum = babiesCount ? adultsCount + childrenCount + babiesCount <= 9 : adultsCount + childrenCount <=8;
    let div = childrenCount + babiesCount  <= 2 * adultsCount;
    let hasAdults = adultsCount > 0;

    return sum && div && hasAdults
}


console.log("3 adults, 6 babies: " + canTheyBook(3,0,6));
console.log("3 adults, 5 children, 1 baby " + canTheyBook(3,5,1));
console.log("2 adults, 4 childern, 2 babies: " + canTheyBook(2,4,2));
console.log("1 child only: " +canTheyBook(0,1,0));
console.log("9 adults: " +canTheyBook(9,0,0));
console.log("4 adults 5 children: " +canTheyBook(4,5,0));
```

Comment: спасибо огромное!!!

Comment: @ВиталийИвашин А ещё можно поставить галочку (рядом с цифрой ответа), если ответ помог вам "Решить задачу"

Comment: @Alexandr_TT ок, не знал